# Refreshing a table without reloading a page in spring mvc using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I am having a simple table which shows basic details about cusotmers. Each customer belongs to one of available customer groups. I also have a dropdown on the top of it where I can toggle between available customer groups and want to update the table with customers belonging to that particular group.  Right now everything happens using page reload which is quite inefficient I know.  Is there a way to use js here and make only the table section refresh without reloading the entire page.

```js
@GetMapping(WebControllerConstants.RIDER_MAPPING)
public ModelAndView riderMapping(@RequestParam(value = "groupId", required = false) String groupId) {
  String group = "1";
  if (groupId != null) {
    group = groupId;
  }
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("riderGroupDetails");
  model.addObject("list", riderService.findRiderByGroupId(group));
  model.addObject("riderGroupList", riderGroupService.findAllGroups());
  return model;
}
```

```html
<select id="category" name="category" onchange="GetAllDetails(this.value);">
  //some options here
</select>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>FirstName</th>
      <th>LastName</th>
      <th>Mobile No</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:set var="id" value="${1}" />
    <c:forEach var="rider" items="${list}">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <c:out value="${id}" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <c:out value="${rider.firstname}" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <c:out value="${rider.lastname}" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <c:out value="${rider.mobile}" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <c:set var="id" value="${id + 1}" />
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(window).on(
    'load',
    function() {
      $.urlParam = function(name) {
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
          .exec(window.location.search);

        return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
      }

      if ($.urlParam('groupId') == false) {

      } else {
        var groupId = $.urlParam('groupId');
        console.log('groupId ' + groupId);
        $("#category").val(groupId);
      }

    });

  function GetAllDetails(value) {
    groupvalue = value;
    console.log(groupvalue);
    var url = "${context}/rider/mapping?groupId=" + value;
    //AJAX works here to send a request but table doesn't refresh.
    window.location = url;
  }
</script>
```

[image: This is how the page looks like]

Comment: This looks like a use case for AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```
//AJAX works here to send a request but table doesn't refresh.
```

Here your AJAX could listen to a response code. If the code says transaction happened correctly you could create a js function that updates the page info while not refreshing it. The new info can be handled from js from the begining or on the response you can pass the info to be updated and pass it to the redrawing function.

Example:

```
function updateDBService(request){

var dataStr = JSON.stringify(request);
var url = '/updateDBService';
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: dataStr,
        type: "POST",
        statusCode: {
            403: function () {

            },
            404: function () {

            },
            500: function (data) {

            }
        },
        //This is your response object (data), which you can use to update the onscreen info 
        success: function (data) {
            redrawInfo();
        },complete: function(data) {

        }
    });
}
```

For this I usually create a controller different from the views controller so I can handle response classes, request classes and all sorts of stuff. Here a controller that uses POST method would be required.

Hopefully this helps you!